# New close reason: include the research

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

After reviewing several Meta posts and related commentary, the moderator team has replaced one of the custom close reasons on the site. The General Reference close reason has been replaced by:

> Please **include the [research](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039)** you've done, or consider if your question suits our [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573) are off-topic.

This new reason more adequately conveys why the community was closing general reference questions (because more research was desired), it provides the same rationale for other questions that might not be considered general reference but are still lacking information, and it also suggests the English Language Learners site, which is helpful for users who may need to learn how to do the research in the first place.

Comment: I have the impression various FAQ updates on ELU have progressively raised the prominence of ELL. Does this reflect inside knowledge that ELL is getting closer to graduating out of "beta mode", or is it entirely an ELU-driven move to steer away inappropriate questions? I'm all in favour of that latest change, btw.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have no information on ELL's progression toward graduation. The motivation is to help users find the most appropriate site for their questions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, ELL is in the graduation queue and has been for some months. There is nothing more that needs to be done by the ELU moderators or community.  The hold up is on StackExchange's end: they need to finalize the design of the site (color scheme, icons, etc) before they can promote it, and the design team is well backed-up.

Comment: The last time the queue was discussed publicly, to my knowledge, was [in this thread on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237472/#comment778914_237588), which put ELL 9th in the queue to graduate.  Since then, the [first site on the list has graduated](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/), and [the second site on the list is partway there](http://meta.expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1281/design-for-expressionengine-stackexchange).  At this rate, ELL should graduate in 2016 or 2017.

Comment: Do you think it would be better that the explanation of "research" has its own page in help section? Some elements from Andrew's answer can be incorporated there also. I think it can be a bit confusing for a new-comer to go to [this meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed). This section gives a hint though: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Excellent, thanks!   I was thinking the same as ermanen; I was puzzled when the research link took me to an apparently-unrelated meta question.  Perhaps @AndrewLynch's excellent answer could be incorporated into the FAQ or even a blog post or a community wiki question like the GR list.

Comment: Doesn't this conflict with the statement in the tour: "We're working together to build a library of detailed answers to **every question about English language and usage**." If you're filtering out questions that can be answered using commonly-available references, then how can you achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2):

(Not really sure if this is an ‘answer’ to a meta ‘question’ at all… but close enough. Since the question isn’t a question, I guess its answer can be one instead.)

One minor niggle has just occurred to me: the *or* in the first sentence is misleading. It would be better to change it to:

> Please **include the [research](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039)** you've done, ***AND*** consider if your question suits our [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573) are off-topic.

The *or* makes it look like the asker should **either** include their research **or** consider whether the question is better for ELL, when in fact of course the asker should do **both**: including your research does not mean the question is necessarily better on ELU than ELL, and ELL expects research to be included as well, so considering that it’s a better fit there does not preclude one from including one’s research.

Comment: I think users have been hesitant to upvote this answer because it's entirely possible that a question demonstrates adequate research, but is still too basic or trivial for ELU (but is a fine candidate for ELL: better than most, because it includes research). In other words, this close-reason is our "golden hammer" for questions which are inappropriate on this site by virtue of the fact that no native speaker would never ask them, *and we want it to be as broad-spectrum as possible*. We only gt 3 custom close-reasons, & we finally got this one after a long hard battle: we don't want it hobbled.

Comment: @DanBron http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359409/can-i-use-has-after-being-a-noun What's your opinion on this question?

Comment: I haven't seen it before and don't have time to dig into the conversation around it, but high-level: it's a question which would never occur to a native speaker, and shows no research, but weighed against that is it's amenable to an expert answer from a linguist (and in fact has attracted one), and is one of those things which would be very difficult to research unless one was a linguist already. I see it's closed but is also attracting re-open votes. Personally, I do not care about its fate.