# Discourage “general reference” questions more prominently in FAQ?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

At the moment, the fact that “general reference” questions are inappropriate isn’t very prominent in the FAQ.  As far as I can see, it’s only mentioned in the section “Why are some questions closed?”, which I would imagine many people may only read after they have a question closed.

Would it make sense to also mention it in a section that users are more likely to read *before* asking their ﬁrst question — eg the section “What *shouldn’t* I ask here?”  It could be worded something like:

> “General reference” — questions that are too basic.  If a single query in a well-known freely-available reference *completely* answers your question (for instance, searching for your question or a key word from it in [Google](https://google.com), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org), or [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.com)), then you don’t need to ask it here.  If you want more details than such sources give, then say so — make clear, in your question, what you want to know.  [Some guidelines.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/761/can-we-come-up-with-guidelines-for-good-dictionary-questions)

I had a memory of a blog post where Jeff gave more general guidelines on what exactly makes a question GR, or saves it from that fate, but I can’t ﬁnd that post now.

(Thanks to @Waggers for raising the issue [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/939/how-to-respond-to-dictionary-general-reference-questions/2000#2000).)

Comment: related: [Please add to faq section “What kind of questions can I ask here?”](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1953/please-add-to-faq-section-what-kind-of-questions-can-i-ask-here)

Answer (score 6):

I could add a section to the FAQ along the lines of:

> #### Where can I find answers to simple and basic questions?
>
> If your question is simple and can probably be easily answered by looking it up, then you may find common online internet resources to be of some help. View our [list of community recommended resources](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools) to find some that may be of help to you.
>
> - Try a **dictionary** if you want to know what a word means or how it evolved.
> - Try a **thesaurus** if you want to know words that have a similar meaning to one you already know.
>
> Of course, if your question isn't adequately answered by these resources, feel free to [ask](https://english.stackexchange.com/ask) here, but make sure you mention the research you've done.

Would this work?

Comment: Yes. just one small change, to include phrases as well as words

Comment: I like this a lot. It's encouraging because it provides help on where else to look, rather than just telling people not to ask gen ref questions. Perhaps rephrase the end a little to keep it peppy and point out that we want specific questions, something like, "Of course, if your question isn't fully answered by these resources, feel free to [ask](http://english.stackexchange.com/ask) here. Be sure to mention the research you've done and what you're still hoping to learn!"